# How to replace capital letters between brackets using regex in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I need to edit a `bibtex` database with hundreds of entries. In fact what I need to do is to replace the capital letters between keys or brackets, such as: `{A}`. I have thousands of them. My first idea was search for `{{` incidences with `Ctrl + D` but this limits my search only to the initial incidences, and the other remain.

My idea is to replace `{#}` (where # is a *wild-card* character that I use to abstractly represent any letter), simply for `#`; but since # could be any letter of the alphabet, I can't use `Ctrl + D` so simple. I know about regular expressions (Actually I know they exist, but not how they are used, I have never even used). I was looking for information about Sublime Text 2 to use but I found nothing basics enough for me.

Could someone explain me how to do it, or show me some useful explanation of regular expressions for newbies?

Comment: input and expected output would be better.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: did you want to replace uppercase letters within `{}` or `{{}}`? What's the expected output for this `Foo{FooFGbb}` string?

Comment: Well, I need to replace uppercase letters within `{}` with just the uppercase letters, but since biTeX uses `{ }` to delimit the fields of each entry in the database, sometimes I have `{{ }` so I was thinking to use `Ctrl+D` before for insert a whitespeace between `{{` before try with the regex for avoid errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*.

If only one instance of a capital letter lies between the curly braces, and you want the braces also removed.

```
Find What: \{[A-Z]\}
Replace With: 
              ^^ Replace with Empty String
```

If you want to replace the capital letter only with a different value or empty string, maintaining the braces.

```
Find What: (?<=\{)[A-Z](?=\})
Replace With: 
              ^^ Replace with Empty String or value of choice
```

If you want to maintain the uppercase letters but remove the braces only:

```
Find What: \{([A-Z])\}
Replace With: \1
```

Comment: No, actually I need to keep the uppercase letters inside the braces but without the braces.

Comment: Well I try to do it, but I don't know what's wrong: I pressed `Ctrl + H`for open the **search and replace** section, there are enable: _Regular Expression, Case sensitive, Whole Word, Reverse direction, Wrap`, and `Highlight matches`. So I copy your last suggestions, but Sublime Text 2 does nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: escape the curly? What does it means? Is it a kind of programmer slang?

Comment: Precede the curly braces with a backslash `\{`, `\}`

Comment: Aaaaah, I did it but the result is the same, Sublime does nothing yet. So I deactivated the options `Wrap`and `Whole word` and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex to match all the uppercase letters which are present inside the `{}`. Replace the matched chars with the string you want.

```
[A-Z](?=[^{}]*})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vZ6eG5/1)

In Sublime text 2 select `Find->Replace` to do a replacement through regex.